# Confusion matrix in QGIS two vectors

Tags: qgis, point, confusion-matrix

I have two vector layers in QGIS. One is points from field-collected data, and the other is a polygonized raster that has been restricted to the raster values that most reflected the field data. Therefore, some of the field points are lying perfectly on the polygon, while others are mismatched.

Example view: (restricted ploygonized raster is black, red points are field)
[image]

I would like to create a confusion matrix that fills this table:
[image]

I am having a hard time understanding how to get information that fills the two empty cells.